# Is it possible to use MAX in update statement using sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to use the MAX function in sql statement.  Here is what i am trying to do:
something like this:

```
UPDATE MainTable
        SET [Date] = GETDATE()

        where [ID] = Max
```

I know this is wrong specially where i put the where condition but cannot figure out how to use max and update in the same statement.  thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
UPDATE MainTable
   SET [Date] = GETDATE()
 where [ID] = (SELECT MAX([ID]) FROM MainTable)
```

Comment: This would generate a 1093 error because You can't specify the target table 'Maintable' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Dwight are you absolutely sure? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/46cb34/2 --- to me it runs just fine :shrug:

Comment: I am reasonably sure that this command will return a 1093 error, here is the exact error: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'new_table' for update in FROM clause

Here is the exact command from a live database: 
UPDATE schemaname.new_table SET date = curdate() where id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM schemaname.new_table);

Table:
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

Comment: @Melanie Answer above is correct because it specified a different table for update, but I shall remove my downvote and do further test to confirm.

Comment: @Dwight do you realise the original question and my answer are about sql server (which is an RDBMS from Microsoft) and **NOT** mysql?

Comment: I was unaware the question was about SQL Server and thought it was MySQL, Please accept my apologies. I was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

One way

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT = (select MAX(id) FROM MainTable)

UPDATE MainTable
        SET [Date] = GETDATE()
        where [ID] = @MaxID
```

That is SQL 2008 syntax, in 2005 you need to do the declaraion and assignment of the variable in two steps

You could also use a common table expression

```
;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MainTable
ORDER BY ID DESC

)

UPDATE cte SET [Date] = GETDATE()
```

Example you can run

```
CREATE TABLE testNow(id int)
INSERT testNow VALUES(1)
INSERT testNow VALUES(2)

;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM testNow
ORDER BY ID DESC

)

-- id with 2 will become 5
UPDATE cte SET ID = 5

SELECT * FROM testNow
```

Output

```
1
5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE MainTable
SET [Date] = GETDATE()
WHERE [ID] = (SELECT MAX(your column) FROM yourtable)
```

Comment: it works fine but i have one other question... why the Get Date() function does not return a timestamp?  it only returns the Date.  i would like to see the timestamp

Comment: You'd be best off asking this as a new question in the Forum. I don't know off the top of my head how to set a DateTime field to a timestamp. Don't even know if it's possible.